# Weird error opening a file in python

Tags: python, unicode, configparser

I am trying to read a file path using config parser and later read from that file

```
>>> cfg_file = './crawler.config'                                                                                          
>>> config = SafeConfigParser()                                                                                            
>>> config.read(cfg_file)
['./crawler.config']
>>> f = config.get('default', 'sites_file')
>>> with open(f) as fp:
...     print fp.read()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'"/home/avi/src/typo.csv"'
>>>
```

I think there is a problem with the Unicode. I can't figure out a solution. If I pass the filename directly as a string it works fine. Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `crawler.config` look like? Note if you have `sites_file = "foo"` the quote characters will be read in as well, which seems to be your problem.

Comment: Try `print(f)` before the with

Comment: you can try `f.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: the quotes were the issue. Resolved. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the value of **'sites_file'** in the config to `/home/avi/src/typo.csv` from `"/home/avi/src/typo.csv"`

**or:**

Replace the quotes before opening the file.

Ex:

```
with open(f.replace('"', '')) as fp:
  print fp.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = config.get('default', 'sites_file')
```

may be f's value will be "/home/avi/src/typo.csv"

which does not exist

```
with open(f) as fp:
  print fp.read()
```

You are trying to read a non existing file